# how to multi foreach in php

Tags: php, html, foreach

Hi i get a tutorial from https://www.codexworld.com/delete-multiple-records-from-mysql-in-php/ and i send id value with :

```
 echo "<td align='center'><input type='checkbox' name='checked_id[]' value=" . $row['id'] . "></td>";
```

and i get it with :

```
if (isset($_POST['bulk_delete_submit'])) {
     $id;
$user_id;    

 $idArr = $_POST['checked_id'];
  foreach ($idArr as $id) {
  echo $id;
}
}
```

but i want send user id too

```
echo "<td align='center'><input type='hidden' name='user_id[]' value=" . $row['user'] . "></td>";
```

and send id and user id to class for delete

```
$class = new manage_user_profile();
$class->seter_delete_user_id($id,$user_id);
```

i want a foreach for get id and user id

thanks

Comment: something like that: `for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['checked_id']);$i++) { $user_id=$_POST['user_id'][$i]; }`

Comment: very thanks this work good

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['bulk_delete_submit'])) {
    $id;
$user_id;    

$idArr = $_POST['checked_id'];
foreach ($idArr as $key=>$id) {
        echo $id;
        $class = new manage_user_profile();
        $class->seter_delete_user_id($id,$_POST['user_id'][$key]);
    }
}
```